# PHP - Get difference between two times

Tags: php, time, difference

I have two variables (which i'm getting from database):

```
$start = '07:14:10';
$end = '07:14:58';
```

I need to get the difference between these.

I think the answer could be `00:00:48`.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Datetime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) this could be done.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('07:14:10');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('07:14:58');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Here $interval will be the object in the form

```
DateInterval Object ( 
         [y] => 0 
         [m] => 0 
         [d] => 0 
         [h] => 0 
         [i] => 0 
         [s] => 48 
         [invert] => 0 
         [days] => 0 
     )
```

And can find out all the values

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

In your case

```
echo strtotime('07:14:58')-strtotime('07:14:10');
```

will work.